# Intellij gradle package name incorrect error

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, intellij-15

I have just opened this (https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_51685286) project in IntelliJ with the following files:

```
src/net/codetojoy/Foo.java
src/net/codetojoy/service/FooService.java
src/net/codetojoy/tests/FooServiceTestCase.java
```

and `build.gradle` contains a configuration for sourceSets like so:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
            exclude 'net/codetojoy/tests/*'
        }
    }
}

sourceSets.test.java.srcDir 'src/net/codetojoy/tests'
```

and On the `FooServiceTestCase.java` file, I am getting an error on the package line saying `Package name 'net.codetojoy.tests' does not correspond to the file path`.

I think it is because of the customised source and test set. But I am unsure how to fix it....

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test` source set definition needs to look more like the `main` one:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src'
        exclude 'net/codetojoy/tests/*'
    }
  }
  test {
    java {
      srcDir 'src'
      include 'net/codetojoy/tests/*
    }
}
```

The reason the previous answer worked in command line but not the IDE is that for the Java compiler, the location of a source file is irrelevant. The `package` instruction is used to correctly place the produced `class` file, but the source file does not have to be in a matching directory structure. But usually an IDE performs this check.